# Cable rubs on mountain bike derailleur

Tags: derailleur

the hole were the cable goes through does not have a guide.  The cable rubs against the aluminum housing.  What is suppose to go in there?

[image]

Comment: Does your rear derailleur have a groupset name or a model number?  It looks somewhat like tourney or similar.

Comment: Could you set the cable in the correct position (at the hex screw) and mark the spot where you think the cable is rubbing?
I don't think anything is missing, looks fairly correct apart from the cable not being in the correct position?

Comment: The cable is not connected to the derailleur, the lower jockey wheel is dead and the chain seems to be suffering from the oil crisis.

Comment: I think it’s normal for the cable to rub very slightly on the exit of the hole the barrel adjuster is screwed into when you are in the smallest sprocket. Where do all the scratches come from? Do you regularly put the bike with the rear wheel into one of these bike stands? I’d rather avoid them or only sacrifice the front wheel. https://cdn.media.halfords.com/i/washford/113179e?w=620&h=480&qlt=default&fmt=auto&v=1

Comment: I think OP is talking about the empty space where the barrel adjuster screws in. Usually there’s some kind of guide piece there. I’m a little more concerned about the large crack running through that piece…